# Jquery not detecting dynamically created element

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to get jQuery to create an alert when the class 'open' gets added to 'ul.foo':

HTML:

```
<span>Some text</span>
<ul class="foo">
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
</ul>
```

jQuery:

```
$('ul.foo li').hide();

$("span").click(function(){
    $('ul.foo li').slideDown();
    $('ul.foo').addClass('open');
});

if ($('ul.foo.open').length){
    alert('ul open');
}
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/j8sL5oh4/1/

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The if block should be `inside the click event handler`, as the code that adds the open class only gets executed when the click event is triggered, and the if block is already read by the time the event is bound. [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/j8sL5oh4/2/)

Also avoid using `alert` as it stops code execution, use `console.log` instead.

Comment: @Dan382 . Glad to have helped :)